# Why docker 1.11.0 use too much disk space on /run/docker/libcontainer?

Tags: docker

I configured a separated storage for docker. It works fine before upgrading `docker` to version `1.11.0`.

I did it via specifying the storage path in `/etc/default/docker` file.

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.4.4 -g /volume/docker"
```

However I observed the docker also occupied lots of disk space(more than 7G) on `/run/docker/libcontainer/` which makes the disk of '/' 100% used after upgrading to latest version `1.11.0`.

I also have docker v1.9.0 running on another box. Only 48k disk space used by `/var/run/docker` folder.

What's the changes made in latest docker? Why it consumes too much disk space on folder `/run/docker/libcontainer/` for container not the storage specified in CLI?